# disable win hotkeys in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, hotkeys

how can you disable the windows hotkeys (win+S, win+D etc.) in windows 10? the methods from windows 8, which involved changing values in the registry, didn't work for me. i'd like to be able to select which hotkeys to disable, but i'll also settle for disabling these hotkeys altogether.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry,first time to giving help,
you can modify reg like this

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
NoWinKeys REG_DWORD 0x00000001 (1)
```

Except Win+L&Win+U can all be blocked
and i use Autohotkey to solve rest problem

Comment: i don't have this kind of folder structure in my registry in windows 10. i can only go up to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies` or `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer`